# Quicksort IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, algorithm

I've taken a few programming courses, and I was wondering if I could get assistance on my Quicksort Algorithm project.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
public class QuickSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        int array [] = {12, 25, 17, 19, 51, 32, 45, 18, 22, 37, 15};

        quickSorting(array);

        System.out.printf("The sorted array is: ", array);
    }

    public static void quickSorting(int array[])
    {
        int pivot = array[0];
        int i = pivot + 1;
        int j = array.length;

        while(i >= j)
        {
            while(array[i] <= pivot)
                i++;
            while(array[j] >= pivot)
                j--;

            swapValues(array[i] , array[j]);
        }   

        swapValues(array[i] , array[j]);
        swapValues(array[pivot], array[j]);
    }

    public static void swapValues(int a, int b)
    {
        int temporary = a;
        a = b;
        b = temporary;
    }
}
```

I keep getting an array out of bounds error.

Comment: @Kevin Java `System.out.printf` is quite unique.

Comment: @greybeard, that was actually a mistake that i made when I posted the thread. Im not sure how to go back and change it.

Comment: "int j = array.length;" -- shouldn't this be array.length - 1?

Comment: I added that to the code but I still keep getting index out of bounds.

Comment: I think you have your conditional backwards. Should it not be ``i <= j``? Otherwise your only valid ``i`` is a value greater than ``j``, which is always out of bounds.

Comment: Also, how do you have any guarantee at all that ``array[0]+1`` (your initial `i`) is a valid index whatsoever?

Comment: @aruisdante I was trying to follow Hoare's method of setting my pivot to be the first element of the array with the first counter to be the one directly after it, so thats why I set i to be equal to that value.

Comment: But that's not what you've done. You've set the pivot *value* correctly, but not the pivot *index*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
    int pivot = array[0];
    int i = pivot + 1;
```

array[0] = 12 => i = 13;

Now,   `while(array[i] < pivot)`  => [i] can't be 13.

you probably meant `pivot = 0;` , `array[0]` means taking the value, that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the swapping  function is called by value and not by reference. Hence actual elements in the array are not swapped. Kindly change the implementation to something like

```
public static void swap(int array[], int i, int j) {
     int temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[j];
     array[j] = temp;
}
```

Next check the bounds on 'i' and 'j' to be correct incase the array is already sorted.

I think this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Parth pointed out,
You missed to put it back to the array. You swapped it, but if your array doesn't reflect that, whats the point?

If your original array was an array of Objects instead of primitive type (Example Integer[]) it would have worked well for you.